# For what value of $p$ would the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p\ln(n)}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

For what value of $p$ would the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p\ln(n)}$ converge?

I have tried using the series convergence test, and limit comparison test, which does't help. So i am considering using the divergence test, and finding all values for p for which the limit is not $0$

Comment: Comparison should work perfectly fine here. Consider comparing against a suitably-chosen p-series. (you'll find that the cases break naturally into convergence and divergence, and that there's one special case.)

Comment: Keywords: "Bertrand series."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly,
$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^pln(n)}
$
converges exactly when
$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}
$
converges:
converges for
$p > 1$ and
diverges for
$p \le 1$.

The comparison test does it
for $p > 1$
and the fact that
$\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^c}
\to 0$
for any $c > 0$
does it for
$p < 1$.

The only problem is when
$p=1$
and this can be handled by
either the
integral test
or Cauchy's
condensation test.

Comment: For the former (in the last sentence): good to remember what $(\ln\ln)'$ is.

Comment: Also what (ln ln ln ... (m ln's) ln)' is.